# MySQL WHERE IN returning one row

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

So I've got what I think is a pretty simple SELECT query. The query itself looks like this:

```
"SELECT id FROM files WHERE name IN ("me_me-about.jpg", "me_me-blog.jpg", "me_me-.jpg")
```

Where I want the ids of those three files in my database. They're in their table. They have unique IDs. (I'm doing this so I can get the ids to insert into a junction table to associate them with user profiles, in case you're wondering.) I created the statement out of a $filenames array, that's just a simple, one-dimensional array of filenames:

```
$stmt = '(';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($filenames); $i++) {
    $stmt .= '"' . $filenames[$i] . '", ';
}
$stmt = substr($stmt, 0, -2);
$stmt .= ')';
$query2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM files WHERE name IN " . $stmt);
```

Query returns one row, the last one. From everything I've seen of the WHERE... IN syntax, that shouldn't be? Is something haywire that I just can't see?

CSV table dump of "files" from PMA (id, name, year [I'm coming back to that once this is working]):

```
"20";"me_me-about.jpg";;"0"
"21";"me_me-blog.jpg";;"0"
"22";"me_me-.jpg";;"0"
```

print_r of $filenames:

```
Array ( [0] => me_me-about.jpg [1] => me_me-blog.jpg [2] => me_me-.jpg )
```

print_r of $stmt in its original form (with my code above):

```
("me_me-about.jpg", "me_me-blog.jpg", "me_me-.jpg")
```

Try-catch to execute. Output the $rows to $_SESSION so I can print_r it on the relevant page:

```
try {
    $query2->execute();
    $rows = $query2->fetch();
    $_SESSION['stmt'] = $rows;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

print_r of $_SESSION['stmt']:

```
Array ( [id] => 22 [0] => 22 )
```

Comment: Also, what do you get when you run the **exact** same query in phpmyadmin or in the mysql console?

Comment: In PMA I get all three rows. Which that's the weird thing.

Comment: Then the error must be AFTER this code you've added here. How are you displaying the output? I bet the error is right there

Comment: See very last edit for my try-catch. print_r of $_SESSION['stmt'] on the page I'm working on (this is a small part of a separate class, with lots of other SQL executes that have gone just fine thus far).

Comment: I knew the error was in the output :)

Comment: fetchAll is the answer, as Allen points out below. fetch has different functionality than I would have expected in the PDO version I'm using. Apparently.

Comment: @Jeff Try if the code in my answer works for you .

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = implode("','", $filenames);
$query = "SELECT id FROM files WHERE name IN ('" . $stmt . "') ";
$query2 = $this->db->prepare( $query );
```

Moreover, please use `print_r` and `var_dump` to debug.

Such as `var_dump($query)`, `print_r($filenames)`

Comment: If you're going to recommend methods of debugging, I would think XDebug or Zend Debugger would be the better choice

Comment: I did that, which is how I know the statement is well-formed according to what I've seen about the syntax, and how I know it's only returning one row. Also, the implode is functionally similar (so thanks for that) but is still only returning the one row.

Comment: @Jeff, is it got single row from PMA? Please provide data (DB and $filenames).

Comment: See edits above for table export and $filenames. It's three table rows.

Comment: I don't know which library you use, but you try use this `$query2->fetchAll();` instead of `$query2->fetch();`. PS: fetchAll for Zend Framework

Comment: That's it: fetchAll. Weird, I was unaware of PDO library differences like that. Thanks much! I don't know how to plus-one that comment as the answer, but if I did, I would.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the result set in order to print all values:

```
while ($query2->fetch()) {
    // output
}
```